# Text symbol section in Table of subsection and subsubsections

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

How to get section symbol § in front of subsection and subsubsection while i am using the code

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox  
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}% <cmd>
  {#1}% <search>
  {\S#1}% <replace>
  {}{}% <search><replace>
\makeatother  
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

then i am just getting the symbol section for section not for subsection and subsubsection. Any of your help be mostly appreciated.

Comment: A quick hint: To have the site software pretty-print a code chunk, just highlight it and click on the `{}` "button" in the ribbon above the editor window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* extend your current approach to cover subsection- and subsubsection-level entries in the ToC:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}{#1}{\S#1}{}{}
\patchcmd{\l@subsection}{#1}{\S#1}{}{}
\patchcmd{\l@subsubsection}{#1}{\S#1}{}{}
\makeatother
```

However, I do not recommend that you go `\patchcmd` route, as it messes up the alignment of the entries in the ToC. Instead, I'd like to suggest that you employ the powerful machinery of the [tocloft](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftsecpresnum{\S} % see p. 10 of the package's user guide
\renewcommand\cftsubsecpresnum{\S}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecpresnum{\S}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works pretty good.